# How to join same tables having same instances in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have following tables in MYSQL

```
Sailors (sid,sname,rating,age) where sid-> Sailor's id, 

Reserves (sid,bid,day) where bid-> boat's id
```

---

My Query is :-

> Find names of the sailors who have sailed two different boats on the same day ?

First of all, I tried to join the two copies of reserves table and adding a condition that bid's must be different.

```
SELECT * FROM reserves R1,reserves R2 WHERE R1.day = R2.day AND R1.bid <> R2.bid;
```

I got output like this :-

[image]

Now, query wants the `names of the sailors`, hence for that I have to  join sailors table with this resultant table.

---

Now, how can I apply join (What are the conditions) operation to get the desired result ?

Comment: The model description of your two tables is incomplete. Also, your query joining r1 and r2 should probably join on `... AND R1.bid > R2.bid` to avoid  duplicates on unordered tuples.

Comment: @Sebas Should I provide instances of the table ?

Comment: What I meant is that it seems some columns are missing in your definition (the day column in reserves for example). I suppose we need them for joining purposes otherwise I don't see how you could join sailors and reserves together

Comment: @Sebas That was a typo !! My bad. I've corrected it now ...

Comment: @Sebas Maybe using `sid` would be an obvious idea

Comment: @RiggsFolly Maybe - but I don't like making assumptions, especially when I see there are missing columns :)

Comment: Barry, what's the sid column representing? Is it something you think can help you relate reserves and sailors?

Comment: @Sebas sid-> sailor's id and bid -> boat's id .

Comment: Okay. Now, why are you joining reserves together? What is the purpose of joining them by day? You could just use the reserves table and order it by day. If you're worried the boat is registered twice maybe using `distinct` would be a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
drop table if exists sailors;
drop table if exists reserves;

create table sailors(sid int, sname varchar(3));
create table reserves(bid int,sid int, dt date);

insert into sailors values
(1,'abc'),(2,'def'),(3,'ghi');
insert into reserves values
(100,1,'2017-01-01'),(200,1,'2017-01-01'),
(100,1,'2017-01-02'),(100,1,'2017-01-02'),
(100,2,'2017-01-01'),(100,2,'2017-01-01'),(300,2,'2017-01-01'),
(100,2,'2017-01-03'),(200,2,'2017-01-04')
;

select s.sid,t.sname,s.dt
        ,group_concat(s.bid order by s.bid) boats
from
(
select r.sid,r.dt,r.bid,
        if(concat(r.sid,r.dt,r.bid) <> @p, @rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,       
         @p:=concat(r.sid,r.dt,r.bid) p
from   (select @rn:=0,@p:='') rn,reserves r
order by r.sid,r.dt,r.bid
) s
join sailors t on t.sid = s.sid
where s.rn = 1
group by s.sid,s.dt
having instr(boats,',') > 0

+------+-------+------------+---------+
| sid  | sname | dt         | boats   |
+------+-------+------------+---------+
|    1 | abc   | 2017-01-01 | 100,200 |
|    2 | def   | 2017-01-01 | 100,300 |
+------+-------+------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
SELECT *,s.SName As SailorName 
FROM reserves R1
INNER JOIN reserves R2 ON R1.day = R2.day AND R1.bid <> R2.bid
INNER JOIN Sailors s ON R2.sid = s.sid
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add table **Sailors** to **FROM** clause and add condition: both columns **sid** of tables **Sailors** and **R1** are equal.

Try this Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Reserves R1
INNER JOIN Reserves R2 ON R1.sid=R2.sid AND R1.bid<R2.bid AND R1.date=R2.date
INNER JOIN Sailors S ON R1.sid=S.sid
```

Also I have added necessary condition: R1.sid = R2.sid which you missed in your query